# .hover() for fading effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a better way to write the JS for this? I'm asking because I read from somewhere that using `.hover` isn't recommended. Also, if I move the mouse in and out of the box really fast, the box fades in and out the exact number of times I entered/left the box. How do I prevent this?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/byB6L/55/)

```js
$(".project-mask").hover(
    function() {
        $(".thumbnail").fadeOut(300);
        $(".description").fadeIn(300);
    },
    function() {
        $(".thumbnail").fadeIn(300);
        $(".description").fadeOut(300);        
    }
);
```

```css
.project-mask { height:260px;position:relative;width:260px }
.thumbnail, .description { position:absolute;width:100% }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="project">
  <div class="project-mask">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/260x260/000/fff" height="260" width="260" />
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      <p>blah blah blah</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of functionality is what [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) was designed for. I wouldn't recommend using anything else. As far as avoiding building up a queue of events when hovering, jQuery has the [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method for that very reason.

```
$(".project-mask").hover(
    function() {
        $(".thumbnail").stop(true, true).fadeOut(300);
        $(".description").stop(true, true).fadeIn(300);
    },
    function() {
        $(".thumbnail").stop(true, true).fadeIn(300);
        $(".description").stop(true, true).fadeOut(300);        
    }
);
```

Here is a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bplumb/byB6L/56/)

Answer (score 0):

This might work too. At least you should traverse!

```
$(".project-mask").hover(function() {
  $(this).find(".thumbnail, .description").stop(true, true).fadeToggle(300);
});
```